# useQuery error object returns empty array for graphQLErrors property

Tags: graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a MERN application that uses react hooks and `@apollo/react-hooks` to perform mutations and make queries. The app works as intended, but now I am trying to work on my application's error handling code. I have this query

```
export const getStacks = gql`
query {
    stacks{
        title,
        notecards {
            question,
            answer
        },
        id
    }
}
`;
```

which I am purposefully breaking by changing it to this

```
export const getStacks = gql`
query {
    storks{
        tile,
        notecards {
            question,
            answer
        },
        id
    }
}
`;
```

When I do this and try to access `stacksError` from

`const { loading: isGetStacksLoading, error: stacksError, data: stacksData } = useQuery(getStacks);`

I get the server error inside `stacksError` and there is no `graphQLErrors`

Meaning when I console log `stacksError` I see this in the console

```
Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

In my App.js file I am using `createHttpLink` with `ApolloClient` and `ApolloProvider`

Does anyone know why `stacksError` is returning the server error and does not have `graphQLErrors` property that would show me that my query is incorrect?

P.S.

I've added `apollo-link-error` to my App.js and when it's called I am able to deconstruct the error object and log what is in the `graphQLErrors` prop as well as the `networkError` prop and in the console I see, respectively:

`[GraphQL error]: Message: Cannot query field "storks" on type "RootQueryType". Did you mean "stacks" or "stack"?, Location: [object Object], Path: undefined`

and

`[Network Error]: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400`

which confuses me even more because it shows that there IS as grapQLErrors property but the contents aren't accessible in my component

Oh! I am also using react-router for my app, maybe I have to pass something or like "connect" my component like you would with redux? idk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`graphQLErrors` is only populated when the server returns a 200 status code but the response includes an `errors` array -- those `errors` are then exposed as `graphQLErrors` in the `error` object returned by the hook (and elsewhere, for example, the ErrorLink).

If an error occurred while executing the request to the server, the error is treated as a `networkError` instead. GraphQL servers typically respond to malformed or invalid queries with a 400 status -- that means those errors will be treated as `networkError` instead of `graphQLErrors`.

Comment: This tracks, but how come this example from the apollo docs shows that when there is a malformed query the errors object still has a graphQLError property? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/ . Am I misunderstanding the example?

Comment: For anyone else looking into this. The above answer is technically correct. I was able to access my errors by doing what was mentioned in this github issue's comment
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/437#issuecomment-471364630